# Checking if 2 BST are equals in terms of values

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a code that determines if 2 BST are equal in terms of values or not.

This is what I came up with, but it only return true and i don't really know what the problem is.

```
 public boolean same(BSTree t2) {
    return sameTree(root, t2);
  }

    private boolean sameTree(TreeNode n, BSTree other) {//L-M-R
    boolean found = false;
    if (n != null) {
        sameTree(n.getLeftNode(), other);

        if (other.search(n.getData())) {
            found = true;
        }
        sameTree(n.getRightNode(), other);
    }
    return found;
}
```

In the main method, I created 2 BST and inserted values in them. Then I called I used to following to call the method:

```
   System.out.println("Are the trees the same: " + tree1.same(tree2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is off. Here's what it's doing right now: You go through each node. If it's found in the other BST, the code sets found to true but what if one of its children isn't in other tree? You recursively call the function for this child and it turns out to be false but DO NOTHING with that returned value. At the end, you only check if the first call, the root, is in the second BST.

To fix this, have a check after each call to see if the returned value is false. If  it is, exit the recursion all-together and return false.

Comment: looking through my code again, you're right, I'll try to work it out again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with this code:

1. You ignore the result of the recursive calls to `sameTree`
2. It only checks if `tree1` is contained in `tree2`. It will return true even if there are more nodes in `tree2` than in `tree1`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different approach and here it is (working perfectly fine!)

```
public boolean same(BST t1,BST t2){
        return sameHelper(t1.root,t2.root)
  }
    private boolean sameHelper(TreeNode n1,TreeNode n2){
       if(n1==n2){
          return true;
         }else if(n1==null||n2==null){   
             return false;
         }else{
           return ((n1.data==n2.data) && (n1.llink==n2.llink) && (n1.rlink==n2.rlink));
       }
```

Just like you guys said, in my previous approach I was only checking the root, and when the roots were the same it returns true.

Comment: This approach now checks if the trees are structurally the same. It would return false if they have the same values but in a different structure. Moreover, the subtrees must be really the same objects, not just equal.

Comment: @henry what do you mean?

Comment: Given two trees with the values 1, 2, 3 in them, they can look quite different, one can for example have 1 at the root, the other 2. You would now return `false` in this situation. I interpreted the original question so that only the same values should be in the trees to be regarded as `same`.